# Custom YOLO v3 dataset in Spyder

Tags: python, shell, opencv, yolo, darknet

I created a YOLO project that can snapshot a live image and create boxes around each detected object from the coco dataset.

However, now I am trying to customize the weights file with a custom dataset. I understand that the cfg file should be modified based off of n_classes, so said file I need no assistance in. Unfortunately, I have not been successful in modifying the weights file via Spyder IDE in Python.

Specifically, I have been following this tutorial [how-to-train-yolov3-custom-dataset/](https://thebinarynotes.com/how-to-train-yolov3-custom-dataset/), and the custom YOLO v3 model is trained with the following command: ./darknet detector train ../data/obj.data cfg/yolo-obj.cfg ../data/darknet53.conv.74

I have already cloned the darknet repository

-git clone https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git

-cd darknet

but did not download the pretrained weights since the command did not work

-wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/darknet53.conv.74

If there is any misunderstanding, please comment below, as I have been trying to figure it all out for over 6 hours. Thank You!

P.S. When I used labelImg, there was no option for PascalVOC to YOLO, then all the annotated images were .xml files, which should be .txt files.

Comment: Instead of wget try just clicking the link (in your question), which starts a download for me.

Comment: no clue what the issue is. I can `wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/darknet53.conv.74` just fine and get a 155 MB file. -- please make your issue reproducible and clarify what exactly the issue is. so far it sounds like your wget failed?

Comment: I guess I overlooked what Micka suggested. @ChristophRackwitz Though, my main problem was running "./darknet detector train ../data/obj.data cfg/yolo-obj.cfg ../data/darknet53.conv.74" command on Spyder, but the tutorial aims for Colab.

Comment: spyder or colab should make no difference, except maybe interfere with the shell command (fetching random files restricted because it could be the behavior of malware)

Comment: Do you still have the issue where your pascal voc annotations need to be converted to Yolo format? If so I can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

its !wget for spyder
and for weights conversion you can try this https://gist.github.com/Amir22010/a99f18ca19112bc7db0872a36a03a1ec

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).